# Android: Make LinearLayout clickable in dynamic ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am displaying a list of events with an image and various information in a horizontal LinearLayout. I want to start a new Activity upon a user clicking any of the information contained within the LinearLayout.

The Activity displaying the list (EventListActivity) has this .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@color/crimson"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/event"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="listItemClick"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="50px"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
            android:layout_marginRight="20px"
            android:layout_marginTop="5px"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="listItemClick"
            android:src="@drawable/alabama" >
            </ImageView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"

            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4.85"
                android:text="@+id/title"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20px" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4.85"
                android:text="@+id/date"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10px" >
            </TextView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/venue"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="4.85"
                android:text="@+id/venue"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="10px" >
            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The list is populated in the EventListActivity.java file, with these relevant sections:

```
public class EventListActivity extends ListActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Event[] eventList = null;

    try {
        eventList = getEventList();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    MobileArrayAdapter adapter = new MobileArrayAdapter(this, eventList);   
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

public void listItemClick(View view)
{
        // launch new Activity
}

public static Event[] getEventList() throws Exception
{
    String url = "http://url.com";
    String json = new JSONReader().execute(url).get();
    JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray(json);

    // eventually from web service
    Event[] eventList = new Event[jsonarr.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);

        String title = jsonobj.getString("eventName");
        String date = "April " + (i+1);
        String time = jsonobj.getString("eventTime");
        String sport = jsonobj.getString("eventType");
        String opponent = jsonobj.getString("opponent");
        String venue = jsonobj.getString("eventVenue");
        String location = jsonobj.getString("location");

        // Location l = new Location(location);

        eventList[i] = new Event(title, date, time, sport, opponent, venue, location);
    }

    return eventList;
}
```

How can I allow the user to click on any portion of the LinearLayout and launch a new Activity? Originally, I tried to do this with an OnItemClickListener but then realized I'm not using ListView. So then I thought I would do it this way, but the main problem is that the events are populated dynamically and I'm not sure how to specify which event is being clicked, because `onClick` only takes one parameter, a `View`. How can I do this?

Comment: can you please know me why you put "ScrollView" as perent becz "ListView" already contain scroll ....?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do seems a really bad code practice. You should use a `ListView`  defining a proper adapter and inflating your row-layout, setting

```
android:clickable="false" 
android:focusable="false"
```

for each inner widget of the list row

so you can configure properly an `onIemClickListener` for your list

There are a lot of tutorials in the web... if you are lazy and don't want to Google [see this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html).